# Update Android TextView from a callback

Tags: android, multithreading, callback, textview

I have the following in my main activity for logging to a TextView element

```
public synchronized void log(String msg) {
    TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.log);
    t.append(msg + "\n");
}
```

I also have the following callback function for handling NFC tags:

```
@Override
public void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag) {
    log("NEW TAG!");
}
```

When using the `log()` from my main activity it works as expected. But When the callback tries to use it, it doesn't log the data, and after that the TextView doesn't update for normal logs anymore. I'm guessing this is because the `onTagDiscovered()` is being called from a different thread. How can I make this work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a Handler to modify a view from the main thread.

Something like this :

```
private Handler handler;

public void onCreate(...) {
  (...)
  handler = new Handler(); // Initialize the Handler from the Main Thread
}

(...)

@Override
public void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag) {
    handler.post( () -> log("NEW TAG!") );
}
```

Or if you dont want / can't use Java 1.8 Lambda notation

```
@Override
public void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag) {
  handler.post( new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      log("NEW TAG!");
    }
  } );
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for :) Thank you!
Note: needs Java 8 for lambdas

Comment: Yes. Without lambdas, the last line could be written like this :  handler.post(new Runnable() {
                   
                    public void run() {
                       log("NEW TAG!");
                    }
                } );

Answer (score 2):

Use `runOnUiThread` if you want to update UI from other thread

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       log("NEW TAG!");
                    }
                });
```

Comment: This a really neat solution! Thank you!